# How to find the page nginx is serving

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have inherited an nginx instance. I am barely more than a newbie when it comes to nginx.

When I navigate to the IP address of the box "http://192.168.1.10" I get a custom page back created by the previous dev somehow.

The nginx.conf looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;


    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

The `conf.d` directory is empty.
The `sites-enabled` directory contains a link `default` which points to `default` in sites-enabled. Here is that file:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
}
```

I have looked in /var/www/html and found the default index.nginx-debian.html that is not the one being served.

So, my question is, where is the file I'm getting back being served from? I'm running on a ubuntu server distro.

Comment: It's a proxy, so there's no file, just the content on `localhost:3002`

Comment: As its using proxy check the process running in port 3002